# Integrate form $\omega=x_jdx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i-1}\wedge dx_{i+1}\wedge\cdots dx_n$ on $S=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}:||\textbf{x}||=1\}$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, orientation

Integrate form $\omega=x_jdx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{i-1}\wedge dx_{i+1}\wedge\cdots dx_n$ on $S=\{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}:||\textbf{x}||=1\}$. $i,j$ are constant.

Doing it from definition doesn't seem workable. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Orientation is external.

I do not know Stoke's theorem yet. I know only basic facts connected with differential forms and some thorems about it working up to $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just do an example.  I am sure you can generalize.

How about we integrate $y \textrm{ d}x \wedge \textrm{d}z$ over the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$
\begin{align} x&=  \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi \\ y&= \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \\ z&=  \cos\theta \end{align}
$

The entire sphere is parameterized by $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$.  Let $R = [0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$ be that rectangle in the $\theta,r$ plane.

So we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_S y \textrm{ d}x \wedge \textrm{d}z &= \int_R \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \textrm{d}(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi))\wedge\textrm{d}(\cos(\theta))\\
&=\int_R \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\left[-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \textrm{d}\phi+\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\textrm{d}\theta\right]\wedge\left[-\sin(\theta)\textrm{d}\theta\right]\\
&=-\int_R \sin^3(\theta)\sin^2(\phi) \textrm{d}\theta \wedge \textrm{d}\phi\\
&= -\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi} \sin^3(\theta)\sin^2(\phi) \textrm{d}\theta \textrm{d}\phi\\
&=-\left(\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi} \sin^2(\phi)\textrm{d}\phi\right) \left(\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \sin^3(\theta)\textrm{d}\theta\right)\\
&=-(\pi)(\frac{4}{3})\\
&=-\frac{4\pi}{3}
\end{align*}
$$

Alternatively, using Stoke's theorem, and letting $B$ be the unit ball, we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_S y \textrm{ d}x \wedge \textrm{d}z &= \int_B \textrm{d}(y \textrm{ d}x \wedge \textrm{d}z)\\
&=\int_B \textrm{d}y\wedge \textrm{ d}x \wedge \textrm{d}z\\
&=\int_B - \textrm{dx} \wedge \textrm{dy} \wedge \textrm{dz}\\
&=-\frac{4}{3} \pi
\end{align*}
$$

I obtained the last equality because I know the volume of the unit ball is $\frac{4}{3}\pi$.

If you need clarification of justification for any step, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use Stoke's theorem to rewrite this as an integral over the interior of the ball.

Comment: Double Hint:  Consider the cases where $i=j$ and when $i \neq j$.

Comment: Umm, Stoke's theorem is little bit ahead of me, so I should be able to do this without it.

Comment: Sure.  Then parameterize your sphere and integrate.

Comment: I have problem with calculating determinant. Is it somehow related to determinant of standard spherical determinant in a way I do not need to calculate it from scratch?

Comment: What parameterization are you using?  The definition of the integral uses the pullback of the form, and the pullback is computed "mechanically" using the exterior algebra.  So you should not have to "think" about how to calculate at all.

Comment: Try doing the integral of $xdy$ and $xdx$ over the unit circle first, using the standard parameterization.

Comment: The method I know looks like that. In this example I use standard spherical parametrization and find its Jacob matrix. Remove its $i$-th row, count determinant, put it in integral and substitute all those $\wedge\cdots\wedge$ with $d\alpha$. So $xdx=\cos\alpha\cos\alpha$. So finding determinant amounts to countin determinan of Jacob matrix without one row.

Comment: @amWhy  My post does in fact answer the question:  it is not a critique or a request for clarification.

Comment: You have not answered this asker's question at the point where s/he is.  S/he has made this clear in the comments, has included the method as s/he is familiar with.  This answer to a question asked by an asker who has not yet encountered Stoke's Theorem, and who told you so, with trying to adapt it;  likely this is a question which is "foreshadowing" subsequent learning of the Theorem. So no, I stand by my comment, but feel free to expand, modify, your answer, ping me when you do, and I'll upvote it!  And please note that I did not downvote your answer, but nor have I upvoted it.

Comment: By the way, when an answer pops up in the "Low Quality Review," which is where I encountered your answer, users have the option of moving on if they think it's fine, or else  deleting, with no comment, or deleting with a formatted comment.  I thought a formatted would be better than leaving no comment.  What you wrote would have been a fine comment to the question.  You would have likely learned from the asker that s/he has not yet covered the Theorem you refer, which means your initial answer is useless to this asker.  You could have done all the chat above, and then post a relevant answer.

Comment: You have to be careful with an attempt to answer a question via hint.  If the hint would make a better comment (as in this case), leave it as a comment.  If after leaving it as a comment, you then learn from the asker's replies, then indeed, proceed to answer, perhaps including the hint, or modifying it to be a more informed hint, or as a compilation of the your responses in a given thread.  Or, as in your second answer, start over and start from the beginning.

Comment: @amWhy  As a Q&A site, the answer is not only for the OP, but also for anyone else looking.  Someone else may have seen Stoke's theorem, and so my original answer could be helpful.  Since it is essentially a complete answer, it should not be in a comment.  In any event, I have posted a new answer which shows how to compute with differential forms a bit without using Stokes' theorem.

Comment: I for one would argue that your hint was not a complete answer, and you would have struck the same conversation with the asker, had you posted it as a comment.  The comment-hint would still be available to "posterity" to help future askers (since you seem to believe it might), but your  justification for leaving it as an "answer" is pretty weak Note, I have not downvoted your answer,  and I deleted the auto comment generated in the review queue.  Wish you the best! Cheers.